# Why cannot hooks be added to command names with underscore?

Tags: expl3, hooks

Consider the following example, which tries to add some code to a command's hook. If I replace `g__mytest_tl` to simply `mytest` then everything works fine. Does this mean that the hook system do not support command names with underscore?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g__mytest_tl

\hook_gput_code:nnn { cmd/g__mytest_tl/after } { test }
  {
    Test~text
  }

\tl_use:c { g__mytest_tl }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does't support the patching of variable with two underscores as they are private and the code explicitly disallows to patch it. There should be never a case where you want to hook into it. Hooks are a tool to change code in an external package. For your own code you don't need them. E.g. to append something to the tl_var you can simply use the relevant tl function.

Comment: Just for the curiosity, I found the check is done by [`\__hook_if_public_command:NTF`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/c23ef2b0a31d461db29cb12e3f3a4001bbc7b6d4/base/ltcmdhooks.dtx#L571-L595).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you type `h` at the error message you will get more info:

```
! LaTeX hooks Error: Generic hooks cannot be added to '\g__mytest_tl'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.66   }
        
? h

You tried to add a hook to '\g__mytest_tl', but LaTeX was unable to patch the
command because it is a private expl3 macro.
```

Your command starts with `\g__` and that marks it as private. A generic cmd-hook is a tool to change commands from another package and so by design it doesn't touch private commands.

If the variable is from your package you don't need the slower hook system you can simply append the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g__mytest_tl
\tl_gput_right:Nn\g__mytest_tl  { Test~text }
\tl_use:c { g__mytest_tl }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Better offer a dedicated command to add something to the configuration.

Comment: @egreg But sequence items does not have labels, how are users suppose to locate a specific configuration?

Comment: @Jinwen Then you want a property list.